# Get-SPOSite find existing sites

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

This is the code that will check if any of the sites listed already exists.

```
 $sites = get-content -Path C:\code\CheckSPSites.txt

foreach($site in $sites){
$url = (Get-SPOSite -Filter{url -like $site} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -ne $null


        if ($url -eq $true){
            Write-Host "$site already created" -BackgroundColor Red
        }else{
            Write-Host "$site not created" -BackgroundColor Green
        }
}
```

It doesn't find the sites when I use the variable *$site* to filter the search.

I've tried putting the variable in quotes (*Get-SPOSite -Filter{url -like "$site"*) and it doesn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Remove `-ne $null` and change the condition to `if ($url) {..}`. Get-SPOSite returns one or more **site collections**, nor `$true` or `$false`.

Comment: Thank you Theo. I've tried running only `$url = (Get-SPOSite -Filter{url -like $site} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)` but it can't find the site

Comment: Still using `if ($url -eq $true)` ?

Comment: no, I've commented the `if` statement

Comment: Then I suggest you try the code from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/263091)

Comment: This doesn't work for me since I'm not manually entering the site URL. The script takes the site name from a list on a .txt file and check if any of the listed sites are already created. The below is the part of the script that isn't working and I'm getting no results.                                                                                                                                 `$sites = get-content -Path C:\code\CheckSPSites.txt
foreach($site in $sites){
Get-SPOSite -Filter{url -like $site})}`

Comment: Whether you hardcode the site or get it from reading a textfile has nothing to do with the code you have failing. Fact is that using a Filter doesn't seem to work, so that is why I pointed you to an alternative solution. Anyway, @DeepDave-MT already posted an answer using that alternative, so I suggest you try that and accept his answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) and [UBK](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/60227/ubk). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

You can use `-Identity` parameter along with the site collection URL to find out the existence.

For example: `Get-SPOSite -Identity https://contoso.sharepoint.com`

```
# Verify if site of same name already exists in SharePoint Online
$siteAlreadyExists = Get-SPOSite -Identity $url

# If it does, stop the script
if ($null -ne $siteAlreadyExists) {
    Write-Host "Site already exists" -ForegroundColor Red
    ...
}
```

If your code fails when site is not present, then you can try following try-catch block:

```
try {
    $siteAlreadyExists = Get-SPOSite -Identity $url

    if ($null -ne $siteAlreadyExists) {
        Write-Host "Site already exists" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Site already exists" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

You can refer to [Number of SPO sites causing issue with Get-SPOSite](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/263086/number-of-spo-sites-causing-issue-with-get-sposite/263091#263091)